# AndroidX Migration

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, androidx

I have a problem with AndroidX Migration when I click migration to AndroidX and click Migrate it gave me this message. How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any non-AndroidX libraries that can be converted? The [first column here shows them all](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings).

Answer (score 0):

could you run flutter run --verbose --debug and share the logs?
I suspect this because newer version of Flutter SDK .
Downgrade to flutter 1.9.7 and it should be fine with androidX migration.

`Command`  :  `flutter version 1.9.7`

Answer (score 0):

That means you wasn't using any gradle that found complicated for migrating to androidx, Your project was migrated to androidx if you want to check that you can refer build.gradle file, you found androidx gradle in build.gradle file.When you get new project and migrate to androidx it gives message like that.